# expect script + how to perform case in expect script

Tags: solaris, shell-scripting, ksh, expect, tcl

the following expect script target is to print the hostname name from linux/solaris machine
and according to hostname results expect script will run linux.ksh or solaris.ksh script

```
expect_sun_script=`cat << EOF
set timeout -1
spawn   telnet 0 $IP_ADDRESS


expect login:           {send $LOGIN\r}
expect Password:        {send "PASS\r"}

expect -re {#|>}        {send "/bin/hostname\r"}
```

so - after I get the hostname name I need to run linux.ksh for hostname - machine1

or if I get hostname - machine2  then I need to run the script - solaris.ksh

but how expect can run the script according to the hostname name?

according to my example below:

expect actually wait for machine1 - but it could be machine2
so its stuck ....

my target is to run linux.ksh or solaris.ksh according to the relevant hostname

please advice ?

```
expect "machine1"            { send "/var/tmp/linux.ksh\r "  } 
expect "machine2"            { send "/var/tmp/solaris.ksh\r" }

.
.
.
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do something like

```
expect "machine1" {send "/var/tmp/linux.ksh\r" } \
"machine2"  { send /var/tmp/solaris.ksh\r" } \
.
.
.
```

Having said that it may be easier to use [uname](http://linux.die.net/man/1/uname) which will return `Linux` and `SunOS` respectively and should make the management of the script much easier as hosts come and go.

```
expect -re {#|>}        {send "PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:$PATH uname\r"}

expect "Linux" { send /var/tmp/linux.ksh\r" } \ 
expect SunOS { send /var/tmp/solaris.ksh\r" }
```

Note that the `uname` command is in `/bin` for Linux and `/usr/bin` for Solaris so we set the PATH before the command to ensure that it is correctly found on either system.